# Redis add element value to a set in a transaction

Tags: python, transactions, redis

I'm very new to redis and I'm trying to do the following inside a tranaction:

increment key
add incremented value from before to a set

using redis commands it would be something like

```
multi
i = incr "value"
sadd "set" i
exec
```

Is there any redis command that would do that in one step with out needing two transactions and handling the value from the code (python code in my case)?

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that directly. You can use a MULTI/EXEC block to guarantee atomicity of the query in the following way:

```
do {
    WATCH value
    i = 1 + GET value
    MULTI
    set value i
    SADD set i
    result = EXEC
} while (result == nil)
```

Comment: Thanks! WATCH was the missing piece.

Answer (score 0):

There is a GETSET (http://redis.io/commands/getset) command for Redis where you can get the "old" value of a variable and set it to a new on the same command.

Almost certain that there is no method to incr a value and add it to a set because they are different data types for redis.

Hope it helps!